# Immediate Window (console-style) output to Excel dashboard from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What would be a simple and efficient way to output multiple rows of string data to an Excel dashboard during data processing from VBA? Ideally I would like it to be in a scrollable popup object (displaying errors from the data that was processed) that can be positioned like a message box without affecting the rows and columns below.

Previously I have used other methods like MsgBox and Cell.Value but they have too many limitations (unable to close, slow refresh rate, not scrollable, etc.).

The VBA Immediate Window is perfect, but it is only visible when the VBA editor is open, so therefore not suitable for dashboard purposes.

Comment: Create a **User Form**? This is pretty vague. Can you show examples of what you currently have? Even if someone wanted to take a stab, there is not nearly enough information here for someone to provide a workable solution.

Comment: It's also unclear what you mean by a dashboard. Can this not just be added to a new sheet? Dashboards in excel are typically formatted on a sheet. Why not just use VBA to output what you want into cells? Seems easier

Comment: I'm sorry if the question sounds vague. As I explained, I'm looking for something like the VBA Immediate Window to show errors and details while data processing is taking place (but accessible from Excel and not the VBA Editor). It does not make sense to write to a sheet, because of focus and screen updating. I will look into using a form for output, but it feels like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could create a userform with a multiline textbox.  You have to set the ShowModal property to false in order to let the main macro continue working while the userform is showing.

It's similar to this example where they create a progressbar. Instead of a bar you can add text to a multiline textbox:

https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/beautiful-vba-progress-bar-with-step-by-step-instructions/

Comment: Thanks, Alex. The link is useful. I'm looking into this and will give feedback.